# Python: assigning variables from function(*args) using argparse

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I'm trying to assign my arguments from argparse to variables. I have two scripts one is the parser and the other is a module. When I try to assign a variable I get a tuple object has no attribute error. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
def main():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A simple front end script interface')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='(run various listed scripts..)', dest='mode')

add_pyrr_command_options(subparsers)
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.mode == "pyrr":
    pyrr.parse_cmds(args)
else:
    parser.print_usage()
```

pyrr.py

```
def parse_cmds(*args):
print(args)
pass
(Namespace(mode='pyrr', plugin_name='ntuser', reg_loc='/user/home', rip_loc='/user/some'),)
```

When I try to assign a variable via researched methods (e.g. arg.plugin_name) I get a `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'pyrr'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `args` is a `Namespace` object

```
Namespace(mode='pyrr', plugin_name='ntuser', reg_loc='/user/home', rip_loc='/user/some')
```

And as your 1st script shows you can use `args.mode`.

In (with corrected indent)

```
def parse_cmds(*args):
    print(args)
    pass
```

`args` is a tuple (because of the `*args`), e.g. `(Namespace(...),)`.  With plain `args` you could continue to access `mode` with:

```
def parse_cmds(args):
   args.mode
```

Another option is to pass a dictionary via `**kwargs`

```
def parse_cmds(**vargs):
   # vargs is a keyword dictionary

parse_cmds(vars(args))  # converting namespace to dictionary
```

I think you are on the right track.  You just to need to distinguish between `namespace` object, dictionaries, and tuples.

In your examples 'pyrr' is the string value of `args.mode`, and also the name of the imported `pyrr.py` module.

Comment: is it generally bad to use string names that match the module name?

Comment: Only if it confuses you!